# What is the best way to have some kind of filter over text columns

Tags: php, validation, yii, input-filtering

I want to have some kind of filter on all of my text fields on my application, to know if a field has some bad content, like filter out bad mouthing of users.

I have thought of some ways

- I could `preg_replace()` over `php://input` stream, and replace bad content
- I could write a custom filter and put it for every single field in every model, which is a LOTand I really don't want to go there
- I could some how override default sting validator of yii ( I don't know how to do that... yet)

I want to do that in a dynamic way and don't want to write a lot of rules

what is the best solution for my situation( from above or any other)?

Update: I'm looking for a way to replace cursing and swearing from the users input and replace it with something else

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are asking

You want to remove

- `Scripts` in the Fields
- `Tags` in the fields, etc

You can go with the [Yii Input Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/input/). It removes unwanted data from the user's data.

You have two ways to do it

- for each form in the controller
- For all the forms in the application globally in `config/main.php`

In case done globally and when you use some `CKEditor` or `tinyeditor` you wont get required html posted. But then you have methods to get them also

**EDIT:**

Your case is to remove the unwanted words in the Users input

so

```
protected function beforeAction($action) {
    //Write your logic here with the posted variables.
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

This can be once in all the controller **(sure this would work).**

**(NOT TRIED)** Another way is to have it in the parent controller which is `Controller`

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is too much for my application .I was just looking for a way to replace cursing and swearing from the users input and replace it with something else

Comment: like in all of my models, I want to not let user enter the word : `Fu*k`, but I need to do this globaly

Comment: If you could do this in every controller, I would suggest you to have them up in Parent Controller see the EDIT

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are over models you can use something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $purifier = getHtmlPurifier();
    return array(
        array('column', 'filter', 'filter' => array($obj = $purifier, 'purify')),
    );
}
```

If you don't like to use htmlPurifier, you can create a filter on any other type by creating a function.